# Authenticate Laravel App with other Laravel App

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

Can I authenticate `Laravel App B` with `Laravel App A` using sanctum? The Apps are in different repositories.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can but you should see what's the most practical solution, here you have a link that might be helpful. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/same-login-on-two-different-laravel-projects

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.